# Will my flash message show up if I do a redirect_to action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I don't see any flash message on the page when I do this from my reset password page:

```
flash[:notice] = "Password has been reset"
redirect_to :action => 'login'
```

Does something not look right?

Comment: Have you added code to display this message on the view file? ie. `<%= flash[:notice] %>`

Comment: Check whether you are setting `flash[:notice]` to another value in `login` method.

Answer (score 2):

For `redirect_to`, you can also do this:

```
redirect_to :action => 'login', :notice => "A flash message"
```